# Failed resolution of: Ldji/sdk/sdkmanager/BluetoothProductConnector

Tags: dji-sdk

SDK Version : 29
dji SDK Version : 4.12

> ```
> implementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.12', {
>     
>     exclude module: 'library-anti-distortion'
>     exclude module: 'fly-safe-database'
> }
> compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.12'
> ```

And I get that error :

```
 AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.i_ron, PID: 15818
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/sdk/sdkmanager/BluetoothProductConnector;
```

please help me I need to be hurry for this project.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you have not called com.secneo.sdk.Helper.install(context).

This is usually done in an override of Application class.  You also need to indicate the new application class override in the manifest.

Look at the sample app:

<application
android:name=".internal.controller.DJISampleApplication"

and in the Application override:

```
public class DJISampleApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

protected void attachBaseContext(Context paramContext) {
    super.attachBaseContext(paramContext);
    MultiDex.install(this);
    com.secneo.sdk.Helper.install(this);
    app = this;
}
```